# field are domains.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory

I want to prove that field are domain. Let $K$ a field. Suppose it's not a domain. Then there are $a,b\in K\setminus\{0\}$ s.t.  $ab=0$. Let $a'$ and $b'$ s.t. $a'a=aa'=1$ and $b'b=bb'=1$.  Then $$1=(a'a)(bb')=a'(ab)b'=0,$$
which is impossible. Does it work ?

Comment: This works well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine.

A shorter proof would be: if $a'$ is such that $a'a=1$, then$$0=a'(ab)=(a'a)b=b.$$